# Amazon Elastic Beanstalk ebextension adds nginx config parameter into default config

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm deploying my app using a zip file which contains my app jar, docker config file and a `.ebextensions` folder which includes a `nginx/conf.d/custom.config` file.

In my custom.config, there is only one line to increase nginx upload file size limit:

```
client_max_body_size: 16M
```

But the console displays:

> Error processing file (Skipping): '.ebextensions/nginx/conf.d/custom.config' - Contains invalid key: 'client_max_body_size'. For information about valid keys, see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html

The [guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-se-nginx.html) that I followed to extends the default nginx setting.
Quote:

To extend Elastic Beanstalk's default nginx configuration, add `.conf` configuration files to a folder named `.ebextensions/nginx/conf.d/` in your application source bundle. Elastic Beanstalk's nginx configuration includes `.conf` files in this folder automatically.

I changed `.conf` to `.config` because the first one does not even trigger ELB environment updating during deployment.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried all .ebextensions method of adding implementation level configuration and it didn't help me in the latest Amazon Linux AMI. for the latest Amazon Linux AMI, You need to follow this structure to increase the upload size. You need to follow this structure to increase the upload size limit.

Add the below folder setup in the root level of your project folder.

Folder structure (.platform/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf)

```
.platform/
         nginx/
              conf.d/
                    proxy.conf
```

Add this line to proxy.conf (Inside .platform/nginx/conf.d/ folder)

```
client_max_body_size 50M;
```

commit this file and deploy again using `eb deploy`.

Answer (score 0):

I think Elastic Beanstalk is trying to process custom.config as an EB configuration file. Try moving `custom.config` to `.ebextensions/nginx/custom.conf` (note the change in file extension)

Comment: According to the guide, it will override the nginx config instead of extending the default config if I move out my config file from `conf.d` folder.

Comment: In that case, changing the extension may be enough. If it works, I can update my answer. When I've done this, I've actually included their sample nginx config in .ebextensions/nginx and just added my modifications to it.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work by adding a beanstalk config file `.ebextensions/add_nginx_config.config` which copies my `custom-nginx.conf` file to the `conf.d` folder of the ec2 instance.

add_nginx_config.config:

```
container_commands:
  copy:
    command: "cp nginx-custom.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/"
```

So my app resource bundle tree looks like this:

```
app.zip
|-application.yml
|-app.jar
|-nginx-custom.conf
|-.ebextensions
  |-add_nginx_config.config
```